# Space between two html email tables Outlook 2007, 2013

Tags: html, outlook, html-email

Quick question, I have two tables sitting next to each other, all is good but on Outlook 2007 and 2013 there is space in the middle of these two tables. Around 50px width.

I've tried pretty much everything I could think of.

Here is what I have.

```
<table border="0"  cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="left" class="w640" width="320">
    <tr><!-- Spacer --> <td height="10" width="100%"></td></tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="w640" height="320" width="320">
        <img src="image.jpg" alt="" style="display: block;" class="w640" height="320" width="320">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr><!-- Spacer --> <td height="10" width="100%"></td></tr>
</table>


<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="right" class="w640" height="285" width="320" style="display: block;">
    <tr>
        <td class="h0" height="40" width="100%"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#4f77bd" class="w640" width="320">
            <table valign="center" align="center" valign="top" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="100%" width="100%">
            <tr><!-- Spacer --> <td height="15" width="100%"  colspan="3"></td></tr>
            <tr>
                <td bgcolor="#4f77bd" width="20"></td>
                <td align="center" width="280">
                    <h2 style="font-size: 24px; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color: #ffffff; margin-bottom: 0; margin-top: 0; text-align: center;">Freeman moves to take organisation globally</h2>          
                </td>
                <td bgcolor="#4f77bd" width="20"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr><!-- Spacer --> <td height="20" width="100%" colspan="3"></td></tr>
            <tr>
                <td bgcolor="#4f77bd" width="20"></td>
                <td align="center" width="280">
                    <p style="font-size: 15px; font-family: 'Verdana', Arial, Helvetica; color: #ffffff; margin-bottom: 0; margin-top: 0; text-align: center;">Name is to focus her future activities on creating an international base for House and its services.</p>
                </td>
                <td bgcolor="#4f77bd" width="20"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr><!-- Spacer --> <td height="20" width="100%"  colspan="3"></td></tr>
            <tr>
                <td bgcolor="#4f77bd" width="20"></td>
                <td align="center" width="280">
                    <p  style="margin-bottom: 0; margin-top: 0; text-align: center;">
                        <a href="#" style="color: #ffffff;">READ MORE</a>
                    </p>
                </td>
                <td bgcolor="#4f77bd" width="20"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr><!-- Spacer --> <td height="25" width="100%" colspan="3"></td></tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="h0" height="20" width="100%"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I'm not sure what is wrong with the code I have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your 2nd table has an attr `align="right"` and property `display:block`. try to remove those things. Hope this will get it fixed..

**HTML**

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="left" class="w640" width="320">
    <tr>
        <!-- Spacer -->
        <td height="10" width="100%"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="w640" height="320" width="320">
            <img src="image.jpg" alt="" style="display: block;" class="w640" height="320" width="320">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <!-- Spacer -->
        <td height="10" width="100%"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="" class="w640" height="285" width="320" style="">
    <tr>
        <td class="h0" height="40" width="100%"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#4f77bd" class="w640" width="320">
            <table valign="center" align="center" valign="top" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="100%" width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <!-- Spacer -->
                    <td height="15" width="100%" colspan="3"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td bgcolor="#4f77bd" width="20"></td>
                    <td align="center" width="280">
                         <h2 style="font-size: 24px; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color: #ffffff; margin-bottom: 0; margin-top: 0; text-align: center;">Freeman moves to take organisation globally</h2> 
                    </td>
                    <td bgcolor="#4f77bd" width="20"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <!-- Spacer -->
                    <td height="20" width="100%" colspan="3"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td bgcolor="#4f77bd" width="20"></td>
                    <td align="center" width="280">
                        <p style="font-size: 15px; font-family: 'Verdana', Arial, Helvetica; color: #ffffff; margin-bottom: 0; margin-top: 0; text-align: center;">Name is to focus her future activities on creating an international base for House and its services.</p>
                    </td>
                    <td bgcolor="#4f77bd" width="20"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <!-- Spacer -->
                    <td height="20" width="100%" colspan="3"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td bgcolor="#4f77bd" width="20"></td>
                    <td align="center" width="280">
                        <p style="margin-bottom: 0; margin-top: 0; text-align: center;"> <a href="#" style="color: #ffffff;">READ MORE</a>

                        </p>
                    </td>
                    <td bgcolor="#4f77bd" width="20"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <!-- Spacer -->
                    <td height="25" width="100%" colspan="3"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="h0" height="20" width="100%"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5yuLbhLp/)